# Navigation Drawer don't work with navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

Navigation Drawer don't get user to destination when he click on menu item. Navigation Drawer showing correct, but don't work. What can be wrong?

I have a navigation menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        ...        
        <item
            android:id="@+id/feedbackFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
            android:title="@string/title_help" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

And navigation graph:

```
  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/feedbackFragment"
      android:name="com.company.ru.ui.FeedBackFragment"
      android:label="fragmegment_feedback"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed_back" />
```

In my MainActivity i have a toolbar(copy all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationView"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconPadding="@dimen/margin_16"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFD000"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And i init my drawer this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    controller = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    initToolbar(getString(R.string.splash_screen_text));
    }

private void initToolbar(String title) {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionbar != null) {
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_dehaze);
        actionbar.setTitle(title);
    }
    toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.RobotoBoldTextAppearance);
    initDrawer();
    }

private void initDrawer() {
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, controller, drawerLayout);
    }
```

I do it by guide, but it's strange, in my opinion all must be ok.

I don't like that i don't use `NavigationView`, i think it's not ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Add a Navigation Drawer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), you need to call `setupWithNavController` with your `NavigationView` if you want to hook it up to the NavController. In addition, you're using `setSupportActionBar()`. As per the [Action Bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar), you should not be using `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, controller, drawerLayout)`, but using the `setupActionBarWithNavController()` method

```
private void initDrawer() {
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Set up the Action Bar with NavController
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, controller, drawerLayout);

    // Now hook up your NavigationView
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, controller);
}
```

You'll also need to override `onSupportNavigateUp()` when using `setSupportActionBar()` as per the [Action Bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar):

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return navController.navigateUp(drawerLayout) || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

I should also note that the `if (actionBar != null)` check and the code within are overridden by Navigation - titles should be set via the `android:label` on destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that work for me

MainActivity

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavController navController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initToolBar();
}

private void initToolBar()
{
    MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout) || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```